# 403 error when making an ajax call through jQuery

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django

This is a Django project, and I have to programme an online shop.
In my html I have the form with the id "search", and I use this 'id' in my ajax code to search and compare with the date base I created.Finally it must show on the screen the possible data which are in my date base like a google finder.My big problem is with the CSRF,in the console I have:
"POST /search/ HTTP/1.1" 403 2295
I read about people having the same problem on this page but I don't know where the fail is.

This my ajax code:

```
$("#search").keyup(function(){

    var cadena = $("#search").val();
    var csrf = $("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val();
    var token = $('input[name=""__RequestVerificationToken""]').val();
    if ( cadena.length > 2){
        alert(cadena);

        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/search/",
            data:{'search_text':cadena,
                ''csrfmiddlewaretoken' : csrf},
            success:function(respuesta){
                $('#search-results').html(respuesta);
            }

        });
    }   
});
```

});

My template(html):

```
        <td>
            {% csrf_token %}
            <input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Search"/>
            <ul id ="search-results"></ul>
        </td>
```

My views.py:

def search_title(request):

```
if request.method == "POST":
    search_text = request.POST['search_text']
    libros1 = Libros.objects.filter(nombre__contains=search_text)
    print("asda");
else:
    search_text =''
    libros1 = Libros.objects.filter(nombre__contains=search_text)

return render('ajax_search.html',{'libros':libros1})
```

my url:

```
 url(r'^admin/',include(admin.site.urls)),
 url(r'^$', 'views.home'),
 url(r'^(search)/', 'views.search_title'),
 url(r'^(libros)/', 'views.libros'),
 url(r'^(carrito)/', 'views.carrito')
```

In the console I've got:

warnings.warn("A {% csrf_token %} was used in a template, but the context did not provide the value.  This is usually caused by not using RequestContext.")

Comment: You can easier debug AJAX activity from your browser's debugging toolbar (e.g. [for chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/network)). This will allow you to inspect the exact response and error details from the server.

Answer (score 1):

Luca's answer should solve your problem. I'd like to share how I normally implement AJAX POST requests. I write the jQuery code inside the template(html) file.

I know this isn't the best practice but doing so allows me to

- Use the `{% url %}` tag instead of hard coding the url in the js file.
- Use `{{ csrf_token }}` instead of fetching the value from the
  hidden input field.

Normally, I have a block called extrajs in my *base.html* file (the one which I extend on every single template) .

Now whenever i need to include AJAX functionality this is how i do it

```
{% block extrajs %}
<script>
...
$.ajax({
...
url:'{% url "app_name.views.func_name" %}',
data:{ ... ,'csrfmiddlewaretoken':'{{ csrf_token }}', ... },
...
});

</script>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: I have tried your answer and I have this problem:                           Reverse for 'tienda.views.search_title' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

Comment: Could you post your urls.py file 
Also previously i had written url:'{% url 'app_name.views.func_name' %}'
....
I have corrected this to url:'{% url "app_name.views.func_name" %}'

Comment: I post my urls.py.Im using firefox debug and it detect a fail in the url

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is that you should make sure the csrf token keyword is inline with the middleware handling it (in your ajax it's `csrtoken`). In my django app, the token is called `csrfmiddlewaretoken`.

The ajax post request should look like the following:

```
        $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/search/",
        data:{'search_text':cadena,
            'csrfmiddlewaretoken' : csrf},
        success:function(respuesta){
            $('#search-results').html(respuesta);
        }
```

Comment: I have changed it, but I got the same result

Comment: @AlbitaVadillo I was talking about the 'csrtoken' in data section of your ajax post request.

Comment: I have it in the same way and I dont know why it doesnt works,do you think it could be the computer? In the console I got :                 warnings.warn("A {% csrf_token %} was used in a template, but the context did not provide the value.  This is usually caused by not using RequestContext.")

Comment: Did you add 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware' to your setting file MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES section?

Comment: Try this: In the last line of your views.py, do `return render(request, 'ajax_search.html',{'libros':libros1}) `